# Audit Logs in SharePoint 2013

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

Audit logging is turned off at site collection level. Still there are records being inserted into the AuditData Table. Is there a way to identify the source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Audit logs will be inserted from Retention policies as well. That is the place you need to check if none are enabled.,

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the following PowerShell command to check if your site is still audited?

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://your_site_collection_url
Write-Host $site.Audit.AuditFlags
```

The `AuditFlags` property return `None` if there is nothing that is currently audited on the site collection.

Many things in a site collection can be audited. SPSite.Audit, SPWeb.Audit, SPList.Audit, SPFolder.Audit, and SPListItem.Audit.

For example, using a script like this you can check if your site, subsites and lists are audited :

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://your_site_collection_url
Write-Host $site.Audit.AuditFlags

foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) {
    Write-Host $web.Audit.AuditFlags
    foreach ($list in $web.Lists) {
        Write-Host $list.Audit.AuditFlags
    }
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the scripts. I did ran them but all the results were none. Not sure, how the records were getting inserted in AuditData Table.